# Proving a function is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the following function is Lipschitz continuous and find a Lipschitz constant

$$y\mapsto f(x,y)\\
f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}\ln(\frac{y}{x})\text{  , } |x-1|\leq\frac{1}{2}\text{  , } |y-e|\leq\frac{e}{2} $$

I have no clue on where to begin to prove this.

My first question is how I should interpret this function, is $x$ a sort of constant?

Comment: Any $C^1$ function on a compact set is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: That doesn't really help me with my problem, I've got several of these questions. So I suppose I can show that this specific function is  Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: If the problem is finding a Lipschitz constant (as it seems from your edit), you can also estimate it using the theorem I mentioned above.

Comment: @RubenMeijs It should help you with the question you asked here. If you think this is insufficient you should ask a different question or explain what kind of help you do expect.

Comment: @RubenMeijs You should interpret the question like this: Let $x\in \left]\frac 1 2,\frac 3 2 \right[$, define $g_x\colon \left]\frac e 2, e\right[\to \mathbb R, y\mapsto f(x,y)$. Prove that $g_x$ is lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @GitGud I do not think so; the exercise asks to prove that the whole fuction is Lipschitz, as far as I understand of course.

Comment: @Romeo I don't understand what you mean. A function is a function. What does 'the whole function' mean?

Comment: @Thomas The question in by textbook has 4 different functions for which I need to show that it is Lipschitz continuous. So I would like a proof for this specific function, such that I can use the same kind of prove on the other functions. That must be possible, because of this theorem but I don't feel like the theorem is enough of an answer for me. I would like to see why this is true.

Comment: @GitGud Indeed, the function $f$ and the function $g_x$ defined in your previous comment are *different* functions. The OP askes to prove that $f$ is Lipschitz, and I do not see how this can be related to the fact that the restriction $g_x$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: @Romeo It's not asking to prove that $f$ is lipschitz, it is asking to prove that given an $x$, the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is lipstchiz. I merely named it $g_x$.

Comment: Ok, I have misunderstood the question, then. Sorry. But I think that the OP should clarify the source of the problem. If it comes from some exercise sheets on ODEs - like it seems to me now - he/she should be aware of the theorem I mentioned above about $C^1$ functions on compact domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting this problem as follows: You are given a family of functions
$$f_x(y):={y\over x}\log{y\over x}\qquad\left({e\over2}<y<{3e\over2}\right)\ ,$$
parametrized by $x$, ranging in ${1\over2}<x<{3\over2}$.

We are told to find a universal Lipschitz constant for each and every of these $f_x$. It will be sufficient to find such a constant for the same problem with all $<$ signs replaced by $\leq$.

When there is no need for an explicit "optimal" $L$, the existence of such an $L$ may be inferred from general principles concerning $C^1$-functions. Anyway, we shall construct in the following  an explicit Lipschitz constant $L$ for this problem.

By the MVT for any admissible $y_1$ and $y_2$ one has $$|f_x(y_2)-f_x(y_1)|=|f'_x(\eta)|\>|y_2-y_1|\ ,$$
where $\eta$ is admissible as well. It follows that
$$\max\left\{\bigl|f'_x(y)\bigr|\>\biggm|\>{e\over2}\leq y\leq{3e\over2},\ {1\over2}<x<{3\over2}\right\}$$
may serve as our Lipschitz constant $L$. One computes
$$f'_x(y)={1\over x}\left(1+\log{y\over x}\right)\ .$$
Looking at the rectangle $R$ of admissible points $(x,y)$ we see that ${e\over3}\leq {y\over x}\leq 3e$ on $R$, and it becomes obvious that $\bigl|f'_x(y)\bigr|$ is maximal when $x={1\over2}$, $\>y={3e\over2}$. Therefore we obtain
$$L={1\over{1\over2}}\bigl(1+\log(3e)\bigr)=2(2+\log 3)\ .$$
The $L$ so constructed is optimal for this problem: Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choosing $x:={1\over2}+\delta$, $y_1:={3e\over2}-2\delta$, $y_2:={3e\over2}-\delta$ we have
$$f_x(y_2)-f_x(y_1)=f_x'(\eta)(y_2-y_1)>(L-\epsilon)(y_2-y_1)\ ,$$
if $\delta $ is choosen sufficiently small.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is this the proper way to prove that a function is Lipschitz continuous? And how can you find the 'best' Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable and the domain of definition $U$ is convex (which is true for the cartesian product of two intervals), then, for $x,y\in U$, by the mean value theorem, applied to 
$$\phi(t): = f(tx+(1-t)y)$$
there exists $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that 
$$ f(x)-f(y) = \phi(1)-\phi(0)= \phi^\prime(t_0) =df(\xi)(x-y)$$
with $\xi :=t_0x +(1-t_0)y)$. Consequently, if you let $M:=\sup\limits_{ z\in U} ||df(z)||$, you get
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le M |x-y|$$
Alternatively, e.g. if $U$ is not convex and $f\in C^1$, you can integrate: if $\gamma$ is a smooth curve joining $x$ and $y$,

$$f(x)-f(y) = f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))= \int_0^1 (f\circ\gamma)^\prime(t) dt \le M\int_0^1||\gamma^\prime(t)||dt$$
with the same $M$ as before.

The last integral is the length of $\gamma$. It depends on the geometry of $U$ whether, for each $x, y\in U$ you can find a curve $\gamma$ joining $x$ and $y$, s.t. $|x-y|\le C \,\mbox{length}(\gamma)$, with a constant $C=C(U)$. If this is true, then you get that $f$ is Lipshitz with Lipshitz constant $MC$.