# Lipschitz continuity in two variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

Prove that $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous, where $$f(x,y) = \frac{y}{x} \ln{\frac{y}{x}}, \ \ \ |x-1| \leq \frac{1}{2}, |y-1| \leq \frac{1}{2}e$$

I tried to solve this, but I find it very difficult to do this in two variables. How do I start solving this?

My first attempt was trying to solve this for the four cases ($x > \frac{3}{2}, y > \frac{1}{2}e + 1$) etc. But this didn't work out very well.

Comment: Do you mean that $|x-1|\leq 1/2$ and $|y-1|\leq e/2$ are the domain of $f$?

Comment: It's not in two variables, it's only one. The map you're asked to prove is lipschitz is $y\mapsto f(x,y)$. Read my comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750540/proving-a-function-is-lipschitz-continuous#comment1562672_750540) with respect to the same question. You'll also find some answers.